# Ordering by HierarchyId but with parent first

Tags: sql, hierarchy, hierarchyid

In one of our databases we use a HierarchyId column. We then select the rows from the table like this:

```
SELECT HierarchyId.ToString()
FROM   Tree
ORDER BY HierarchyId DESC
```

This lays it out in a nice hierarchical structure but with all of the nodes in reverse order like this:

```
1/13/
1/12/123/
1/12/122/
1/12/121/
1/12/
1/11/
1/
```

However we would like the nodes to stay in this order but with the parent above the child nodes like this:

```
1/
1/13/
1/12/
1/12/123/
1/12/122/
1/12/121/
1/11/
```

The only solution that I can think of involves a recursive CTE which would negate a lot of the benefits of using HierarchyId. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, hopefully it will work.

```
SELECT HierarchyId.ToString()
FROM   Tree
ORDER BY cast(HierarchyId as nvarchar(100)) DESC
```